# How to flash message with variables in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to flash a message with a variable in flask. Can anyone tell me how can i do so.
For example:

```py
a = 3
flash("message + A + message continues")
```

I want to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to insert your variable into the string that you give to flash().

There are different ways to achieve this:

```
a = 3
message = "message {} message continues".format(a)  # Using the format method
message = f"message {a} message continues"  # Using f-strings (Python >= 3.6)
message = "message %d message continues" % (a)  # % Formatting
message = "message " + str(a) + " message continues"  # Concatenation
flash(message)
```

Comment: Hi I have another problem. Please let me know if you can solve it
I have 2 variables
a=['1'] //This is an array
b=1 //This is a integer 
I want (a==b) to be true.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will need to get the element of your list a first by using for example a[0]. If the '1' is supposed to be a string, you need to convert it to an integer: int(a[0]). This is then the value you can compare with b. Since both questions are related to Python data types, I would like to advice you to read up on those to obtain the required knowledge to deal with these type of problems.